# Strange NHibernate exception

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm getting a strange NHibernate exception when I try and create a SessionFactory.  I've narrowed down the exception 'Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Mapping.Bag' to type 'NHibernate.Mapping.IKeyValue' to the following mapping on the Company object:

```
<bag name="Images" cascade="none">
  <key column="CompanyId" property-ref="Images"/>
  <one-to-many class="GwDbImage"/>
</bag>
```

This is the mapping for GwDbImage:

```
<class name="GwDbImage" table="Images" >
<id name="ImageId">
  <column name="ImageId" sql-type="int" not-null="true"/>
  <generator class="native"/>
</id>

<property name="FileName"  />
```

The definition of Images on the Company object is as follows:

```
public virtual IList<GwDbImage> Images { get; set; }
```

I know it's vague but does anyone know what is wrong / point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Jon

Comment: What .Net datatype are you using in your code for Images.GwDbImage?

Comment: Show your Company class definition

Comment: Sorry, here's the definition in the Company object:  public virtual IList<GwDbImage> Images { get; set; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you specify the property-ref attribute ?
Is it necessary in your case ?  Do you join with another column other then your PK in your related table ?

Answer (score 0):

you declared Images property as IDictionary while bag should be declared as IList